# List of Lists to dictionary where key is entry value and value is entry value

Tags: python

I have a list of lists:

```
[[0, 1, 2,], [130, 131], [142, 143]]
```

I want to transform this list `l` to a dictionary of the following form:

```
{'0': 0, '1': 0, '2':'0, '130': 1, '131: 1, '142': 2, '143': 2}
```

So the key is the list element. The respective value is the entries name from the sublist of `l`. I hope you can follow my issue.

I tried the following code, which didn't work at all.

```
cluster_list = list(range(len(list(l))))

dictionary = dict(zip(cluster_list, l))
```

I have to add: Every sublist states which nodes are members of the same cluster. So every node is only present once.

I hope we can solve this issue together. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `enumerate`

**Ex:**

```
data = [[0, 1, 2], [130, 131], [142, 143]]
print({i: k for k, v in enumerate(data) for i in v})
#or print({str(i): k for k, v in enumerate(data) for i in v}) #For string key.
```

**Output:**

```
{0: 0, 1: 0, 2: 0, 130: 1, 131: 1, 142: 2, 143: 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
l = [[0, 1, 2,], [130, 131], [142, 143]]
d = {}
for n in range(len(l)):
    for item in l[n]:
        d[item] = n
print(d)
```